# This bash script is giving me an error and I can't figure out why

Tags: bash

I'm following some tutorials here and whenever I execute this, I get

```
Do you want to create a bukkit server on this computer? (Hint: answer YES or NO) > no
answered no
./test.sh: line 44: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./test.sh: line 44: 'else'
```

here's the script:

```
while true; do
    read -p "Do you want to create a bukkit server on this computer? (Hint: answer YES or NO) > " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) echo answered yes; INSTALL="Y"; break;;
        [Nn]* ) echo answered no; break;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done

if [ -z "$INSTALL" ];
    echo "Yay!"
else
    echo "Sadface!"
fi
```

i'm a bash newbie :/

Comment: You may also want to _explicitly_ clear `INSTALL` before your loop just in case some other piece of code has set it. If it was set to _anything_ and you answer "no", the results will not be what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `then` keyword after the condition:

```
if [ -z "$INSTALL" ]; then
    echo "Yay!"
else
    echo "Sadface!"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `then` after the `if`:

```
while true; do
read -p "Do you want to create a bukkit server on this computer? (Hint: answer YES or NO) > " yn
case $yn in
[Yy]* ) echo answered yes; INSTALL="Y"; break;;
[Nn]* ) echo answered no; break;;
* ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
esac
done

if [ -z "$INSTALL" ]; then
echo "Yay!"
else
echo "Sadface!"
fi
```